# Adding certain lengthy elements to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, string-length

I'm doing a project for my school and for now I have the following code:

```
def conjunto_palavras_para_cadeia1(conjunto):
acc = []
conjunto = sorted(conjunto, key=lambda x: (len(x), x))

def by_size(words, size):
    result = []
    for word in words:
        if len(word) == size:
            result.append(word)
    return result

for i in range(0, len(conjunto)):
    if i > 0:
        acc.append(("{} ->".format(i)))
        acc.append(by_size(conjunto, i))

acc = ('[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, acc)))
print( acc.replace(",", "") and acc.replace("'", "") )


conjunto_palavras_para_cadeia1(c)
```

I have this list: c = ['A', 'E', 'LA', 'ELA'] and what I want is to return a string  where the words go from the smallest one to the biggest on in terms of length, and in between they are organized alphabetically. I'm not being able to do that...

- **OUTPUT:** [;1 ->, [A, E], ;2 ->, [LA], ;3 ->, [ELA]]
- **WANTED OUTPUT**: ’[1->[A, E];2->[LA];3->[ELA]]’

Comment: Can you use `itertools`? I'm going to guess not, but doesn't hurt to ask. What about `collections.OrderedDict`? Any imports at all?

Comment: Hey! I can use itertools, yes! :)

Comment: your output has a very strange format..

Comment: acc = ('[%s]' % ''.join(map(str, acc)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at your program, the only issue appears to be when you are formatting your output for display. Note that you can use `str.format` to insert lists into strings, something like this:

```
'{}->{}'.format(i, sublist)
```

---

Here's my crack at your problem, using `sorted` + `itertools.groupby`.

```
from itertools import groupby

r = []
for i, g in groupby(sorted(c, key=len), key=len):
    r.append('{}->{}'.format(i, sorted(g)).replace("'", ''))

print('[{}]'.format(';'.join(r)))
[1->[A, E];2->[LA];3->[ELA]]
```

A breakdown of the algorithm stepwise is as follows -

- sort elements by length
- group consecutive elements by length
- for each group, sort sub-lists alphabetically, and then format them as strings
- at the end, join each group string and surround with square brackets  `[]`

Comment: That's it!! Thank you very much for the help :) I was able to 1) Understand 2) Do what I wanted to!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Shortest solution (with using of pure python):

```
c = ['A', 'E', 'LA', 'ELA']

result = {}

for item in c:
  result[len(item)] = [item] if len(item) not in result else result[len(item)] + [item]

str_result = ', '.join(['{0} -> {1}'.format(res, sorted(result[res])) for res in result])
```

I will explain:
We are getting items one by one in loop. And we adding them to dictionary by generating lists with index of word length.

We have in result:

```
{1: ['A', 'E'], 2: ['LA'], 3: ['ELA']}
```

And in str_result:

```
1 -> ['A', 'E'], 2 -> ['LA'], 3 -> ['ELA']
```

Should you have questions - ask

Comment: `result = defaultdict(list)` would make this much nicer

Comment: I updated my answer - added transform to string and ordering, as you need.  
But giving totally exact answer to educational tasks - not a good idea.   :)
Because the goal - to get experience and knowledge. Good luck in education!

Comment: They already did the heavy lifting and figured out everything except output representation. I believe it's alright to throw OP a bone every once in a while for their efforts ;)